# Recursive Method that returns the index of an element java

Tags: java, recursion, methods, iteration

I am trying to search a sorted array for a number that i choose. if the array contains this number i want to return the indices of each occurrence. I need to write to methods to do this task. one Recursively and one iteratively. I have started the recursive method below.

```
public int findRecursive(T anEntry) {
    return binarySearchRecursive(0, length - 1, anEntry);
}

private int binarySearchRecursive(int first, int last, T desiredItem) 
{
    int position = 0;
    int mid = (first + last) / 2;
    if (first > last ||  (desiredItem.compareTo(list[position]) != 0))
        position =  -(position + 1);
    else if (desiredItem.equals(list[mid]))
        position = mid;
    else if (desiredItem.compareTo(list[mid]) < 0)
        position = binarySearchRecursive(first, mid -1, desiredItem);
    else 
        position = binarySearchRecursive(mid + 1, last, desiredItem);
    return position;
}
```

Here is the array/output that should be expected

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AList<Integer> testList = new AList<Integer>();
    testList.add(1);
    testList.add(3);
    testList.add(2);
    testList.add(5);
    testList.add(7);
    testList.add(2);
    testList.add(4);

 //* question 5
     //* should output 1, -8, 4
     // my out is returning -1, -1, -1


    testList.sort();
    System.out.println(testList.findRecursive(2));
    System.out.println(testList.findRecursive(8));
    System.out.println(testList.findRecursive(4));
    System.out.println("");
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Did you mean `int mid = (first + last) / 2;`?

Comment: Not sure I understand can you rephrase the question please

Comment: i rephrased the question. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Nope, where is the `findRecursive` method?

Comment: its the binarySearchRecursive method that is listed above

Comment: sorry i completly forgot the findRecursive method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of small changes required to your recursive method in order to get the desired output -

```
private int binarySearchRecursive(int first, int last, T desiredItem) 
{
    int position = 0;
    int mid = (first + last) / 2;
    if (first > last)
        position =  -(last + 1);
    else if (desiredItem.equals(list[mid]))
        position = mid;
    else if (desiredItem.compareTo(list[mid]) < 0)
        position = binarySearchRecursive(first, mid -1, desiredItem);
    else 
        position = binarySearchRecursive(mid + 1, last, desiredItem);
    return position;
}
```

Both changes were in the termination area.  When first > last you have exhausted the search, you don't need the comparison for desired item.  Also in the termination you should return `-(last+1)`, not `-(position+1)` as position will always be 0.